# Magento 1.8.1.0 WYSIWYG editor is not displaying thumbnails in image manager

Tags: magento-1.8, image, ce-1.8.1.0, wysiwyg, thumbnail

I am posting this for comments about the bug, and to help anyone who have the same issue. (answer posted by myself)

When using the WYSIWYG editor and inserting images the image manager is not displaying the thumbnail images.

Looking at the image URL produced by magento I can see that the url is missing the /wysiwyg/ portion

http://site.domain/media//.thumbs/ex_logo_sm.jpg?rand=1392103618

It looks purely missing, as taken note by the double // in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing the code, it looks to me that there is a constant missing in the helper routine located in `Mage_Cms_Helper_Wysiwyg_Images::getBaseUrl()`

The routine is as such:

```
public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . '/';
    }
```

and making the change to

```
public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config::IMAGE_DIRECTORY . '/';
    }
```

fixes the issue.

This is called from `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage::getThumbnailUrl()`

```
return str_replace('\\', '/', $this->getHelper()->getBaseUrl() . $thumbSuffix) . $randomIndex;
```

which clearly outputs the wrong url without the constant in place.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this only happens on some of our severs.. My local site grabs the img src from a controller/action looking something like this: `http://mysite.dev/index.php/bdc/cms_wysiwyg_images/thumbnail/file/RWxpfmFisXRoLnBuZw--/key/adbe142dbd98303651b427bb36a337c0/` which didn't seem to have this issue. Your fix worked on the other enviroments. THanks

Comment: If this is the same code base it's hard to explain, cause the wysiwyg prefix is added by default. I've seen core hacks floating around that remove the wysiwyg prefix to allow content managers to pick any image. This would mean some servers are running different code or maybe some opcode cache was still serving the older version?

Comment: @erfan - it is possible the admin setting 'Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog' may be involved in the difference. I have not tested that statement, but recall that it did have an effect on the url outcome/issue when I was debugging the issue that time ago.

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue on a client site, there were actually quite a few elements at play, and I can offer a probably explanation as to how the non-existent image issue was trigged, even though it seemingly should not be possible:

1. The issue as described above was present, whereby Magento was checking for `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/image.jpg`, as opposed to the correct location of `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/wysiwyg/image.jpg`, and if present displaying a link to the incorrect URL of `http://example.com/media//wysiwyg/.thumbs/image.jpg` fd
2. We had APPSEC-212 installed, which introduced the use of `realpath()` to remove a security issue, however the combination of this and the usage of a symlink on our `media` directory was causing `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage::getThumbsPath()` to return a directory of `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs`, as opposed to `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/wysiwyg` - the reason is because this method makes a conditional check which did not evaluate to true, as our media directory had been expanded via `realpath()` and as such did not return 0 for the `strpos()` check, see the check below, line 6:

   ```
   public function getThumbsPath($filePath = false)
   {
       $mediaRootDir = Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
       $thumbnailDir = $this->getThumbnailRoot();

       if ($filePath && strpos($filePath, $mediaRootDir) === 0) {
           $thumbnailDir .= DS . dirname(substr($filePath, strlen($mediaRootDir)));
       }

       return $thumbnailDir;
   }
   ```
3. This is unique to us, but we were also denying access to dotfile directories, and had not previously noticed this as a problem because we had never served them until we installed APPSEC-212, so even when we fixed the problem we were getting 404's on anything in `.thumbs`

The problem we have experienced still exists in 1.9.1.0 (the latest version at the time of writing) - I'm going to assume no-one notices because the images still serve 'on the fly' without using the `.thumbs` directory, it was only with the introduction of APPSEC-212, combined with a symlinked `media` directory, that caused the thumb files to be generated in the incorrect location, which then caused the incorrectly checked path to return true, and for us to subsequently see 404's on our images.

Funnily enough, APPSEC-212 would have fixed the issue if it weren't for our symlinked `media` directory.

By the way, here are our modifications:

In app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php:

```
@@ -89,7 +89,7 @@ public function getStorageRoot()
      */
     public function getBaseUrl()
     {
-        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . '/';
+        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . '/' . Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config::IMAGE_DIRECTORY . '/';
     }

     /**
```

In app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php:

```
@@ -336,7 +336,7 @@ public function getThumbnailUrl($filePath, $checkFile = false)
         $mediaRootDir = $this->getHelper()->getStorageRoot();

         if (strpos($filePath, $mediaRootDir) === 0) {
-            $thumbSuffix = self::THUMBS_DIRECTORY_NAME . DS . substr($filePath, strlen($mediaRootDir));
+            $thumbSuffix = self::THUMBS_DIRECTORY_NAME . DS . substr($filePath, strlen(realpath(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir())));

             if (! $checkFile || is_readable($mediaRootDir . $thumbSuffix)) {
                 $randomIndex = '?rand=' . time();
@@ -405,8 +405,8 @@ public function resizeOnTheFly($filename)
      */
     public function getThumbsPath($filePath = false)
     {
-        $mediaRootDir = Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
-        $thumbnailDir = $this->getThumbnailRoot();
+        $mediaRootDir = realpath(Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir());
+        $thumbnailDir = realpath($this->getThumbnailRoot());

         if ($filePath && strpos($filePath, $mediaRootDir) === 0) {
             $thumbnailDir .= DS . dirname(substr($filePath, strlen($mediaRootDir)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several errors coming together.

By default Magento seems to save the thumbs in the directory `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/wysiwyg/`. But `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage::getThumbnailUrl()` looks for the thumb in `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/`.

The error only gets triggered if a thumb is in `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/`. I could not find out under what conditions a thumb is saved in the wrong directory. But at least it explains why only some servers show this problem.

So in addition to what ProxiBlue said you'll have to change `Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage::getThumbnailUrl()` from

```
public function getThumbnailUrl($filePath, $checkFile = false)
{
    $mediaRootDir = $this->getHelper()->getStorageRoot();

    if (strpos($filePath, $mediaRootDir) === 0) {
        $thumbSuffix = self::THUMBS_DIRECTORY_NAME . DS . substr($filePath, strlen($mediaRootDir));

        if (! $checkFile || is_readable($mediaRootDir . $thumbSuffix)) {
            $randomIndex = '?rand=' . time();
            return str_replace('\\', '/', $this->getHelper()->getBaseUrl() . $thumbSuffix) . $randomIndex;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

to

```
public function getThumbnailUrl($filePath, $checkFile = false)
{
    $mediaRootDir = Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir() . DS;

    if (strpos($filePath, $mediaRootDir) === 0) {
        $thumbSuffix = self::THUMBS_DIRECTORY_NAME . DS . substr($filePath, strlen($mediaRootDir));

        if (! $checkFile || is_readable($this->getHelper()->getStorageRoot() . $thumbSuffix)) {
            $randomIndex = '?rand=' . time();
            return str_replace('\\', '/', $this->getHelper()->getBaseUrl() . $thumbSuffix) . $randomIndex;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Preferably by setting up a module and not by overwriting the core file.